# Setting size of editor for chat UI in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I'm implementing chat feature and want to make sure that the `Editor` and `Button` are perfectly located at the bottom of the screen.

I created a `Grid` for the controls to produce this layout
[image]

The problem I'm having is with the `Editor` width because if I get it to look right on Android, it's not perfect on iOS and vice versa.

Here's how I approached it:

```
<Grid
    RowDefinitions="50"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,50"
    RowSpacing="0"
    ColumnSpacing="5"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    Margin="5,5,5,5">
   <Editor
      Grid.Column="0" />
   <Button
       Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Other than entering some arbitrary number for `WidthRequest` for the `Editor`, how do I set the width for it so that it always takes up all the available space and look like it in the picture?

Comment: Set HorizontalOptions on the Editor

Comment: I tried `StartAndExpand` but it didn’t work. I ended up with a tiny `Editor` on the left, not spanning across the screen.

Comment: Try FillAndExpand

Comment: `FillAndExpand` definitely works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` as Jason suggested like below, it looks right on `Android` and `iOS`.

```
<Grid
    RowDefinitions="50"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,50"
    RowSpacing="0"
    ColumnSpacing="5"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Margin="5">
   <Editor
      Grid.Column="0" />
   <Button
       Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```